# Method error in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods

this may be simple or fairly difficult...I have no idea either way. 
Here's my code:

```
package looping;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayrollMethods2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hours = 0;
        double wr = 0;
        double pay;

        getData(hours, wr);

        pay = calculatePay(hours, wr);

        System.out.println(pay);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public static void getData(Integer hours, Double wr)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Please enter your wage rate ");
        wr = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Please enter your hours work ");
        hours = kb.nextInt();
    }



    public static double calculatePay(int hours, double wr)
    {
        if(hours <= 40)
            return hours * wr;
        else
            return (40 * wr) + ((hours - 40) * (1.5* wr));
    }

}
```

I want to return the method "getData()" so that when I enter hours and wr on the keyboard, it will  return the total. However, it return a total of 0.0 no matter what I press. I know it has something to do with me assigning a value of 0 to the variables and also that the method is "void". But I have no idea how to modify the getData() method so that it returns the proper values.

Comment: For one, Java is pass by value.

Comment: Sorry new to JAVA, but I changed the main method to "getData(Interger, Double);"..I think that's what you meant but still nothing, but shouldn't there be a problem with the assigned variables initialized in main?

Comment: @Circuuspeatnutz: It's a matter of scope and pass by value. You are assigning to the parameters. If you used an IDE like Netbeans, it would warn you of this. Since you aren't storing the values anywhere outside that method, they essentially get thrown away in `getData`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand the pass value now lol.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Pass by value has never stopped anyone from modifying objects inside of a function. The problem here is that `Integer` objects are immutable.

Comment: @John In `getData()`, OP is reassigning references to the parameters `hours` and `wr` and assuming that those should change in the calling code in `main()` in the arguments pass to the method. This has everything to do with pass by value and nothing to do with immutability.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are facing is because the variables hours & wr are being passed by value to getData() so getData function has its own copy of the variables hours & wr.

**main :(initialize)**

```
Variable    Value    Memory Address
hours         0       44444
wr            0.0     55555
```

**getData :** 
  hours & wr are different than main so they have different address

```
Variable    Value    Memory Address
hours         0       66666
wr            0.0     77777
```

user enters values now : hours - 10 , wr - 20

```
Variable    Value    Memory Address
hours         10       66666
wr            20.0     77777
```

**main :** When control comes back to main the  value of hours & wr is stil 0

```
Variable    Value    Memory Address
hours         0       44444
wr            0.0     55555
```

***Solution :***

This problem can be resolved by encapsulating the salary info into a object and then passing that object around( Objects are passed by Reference in Java) :

```
class Salary
{
  int hours;
  double wr;
}
```

Now in getData you can create an object of data Salary based on user input info and pass that Object to calculatePay

```
public static Salary getData()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Salary sal = new Salary();

    System.out.print("Please enter your wage rate ");
    sal.wr = kb.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter your hours work ");
    sal.hours = kb.nextInt();

    return sal;
}

public static double calculatePay(Salary sal)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank u! I think I understand the variable error. Its because hours and wr had a defined value of "0' right?

Comment: No its becuase you were passing those variables by value..so any modifications you make to them in getData will not be propogated

Answer (score 2):

You need to either make wr and hours into static variables inside the class, or you need to have two getData methods and have them return, or you need to make a separate object to store wr and hours.

When you call a method variables are *copied* into the method. So when you change them inside the method it doesn't change anything outside the method. (If you pass an object in then a reference to the object is passed by value, so in that cases changes inside the object will be seen).

Answer (score 2):

Java is [pass-by-value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). It looks like you are trying to modify the parameters, which are locally scoped so you won't see the changes in `main`.

Java doesn't allow multiple returns, so you'll either have to create a class to pass back, or you can put the calls from the `getData` method into the `main` method.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, when you modify an object inside of a function, the changes are reflected outside of that function. Why do Integer objects behave differently? Take a look at the following code.

```
psv main (String[] args) {
    Integer i = new Integer(1);
    increment(i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 1!
}

void increment(Integer i) { i = i + 1; }
```

We expected a 2 to be printed, but a 1 is printed instead. This is because Integer is **immutable**.

Typically, if you pass an object into a function an modify its contents, you get a modified object. Because, when immutable objects are modified, a completely new object is created instead. If you create a completely new object, you are no longer modifying the old object!

Therefore, incrementing our `Integer` created an entirely new `Integer` that is local to the increment function.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with immutability. If instead of `Integer`, you used some custom, mutable type, say `Custom`, and changed the reference, that change would not be reflected in the calling code. This is a consequence of Java being pass by value. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I created a custom object and tried to assign a primitive `int` to it, my program would probably crash. The magic lies in `Integer`'s custom `=` operator. Why does it require a custom assignment operator? Because it has no `setValue()` method. Why doesn't it have a `setValue()` method? Because it is immutable.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. Given `public class Custom {}`, if you pass a `Custom` object that's bound to a method parameter `Custom c` and inside the method do `c = new Custom()`, that change will not be reflected in the calling code. This is what passing by value is all about. `Integer` is immutable, fine. But the root problem here is that reassigning references to parameter variables is not reflected in the arguments used to invoke the method. Java is pass by value. (It's hard to say all this in comments, would be easier in chat.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The OP never once used the `new` operator, and neither did I, so you are comparing apples to oranges in your example.

Comment: Again the `new` makes no difference, it's the `=`, reassigning references, that does. `hours = ...`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And why does assignment to an `Integer` create a new reference?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48416/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-john)

Comment: My issue is with this statement: `We expected a 2 to be printed, but a 1 is printed instead. This is because Integer is immutable.` It's not because `Integer` is immutable, it's because, even if you don't  see it, there's a change of reference that occurs (and references are passed by value). The fact that `Integer` is used here doesn't matter. You could have had `Custom c` as a parameter and `c = someType.getCustom();` and OP would experience the same thing.